# How to fit together ngModel ngFor in select tag with options angular

Tags: angular

Please i have problem fitting together `ngModel` `ngFor` in `select` `option` in angular.
When i clicked the edit button. I can't see the type is pre-selected.
here is my source code:

```
<select class="form-control col-sm-8" id="type" [(ngModel)]="category.type" name="type">
          <option *ngFor="let elt of categoryTypes" [ngValue]="elt.code">
            {{elt.value}}
          </option>
</select>
```

the `category` contains all data about the selected category. but the type is not pre-selected.
the `category.type` contains the `elt.code` value not the `elt.value`

my component.ts code:

```
openEditModal(element, type: string) {
    console.log("this is the category to edit ",element);
    this.category = element;
    }

getAllTypes() {
    this.categoryService.getAllTypes().then(response => {
      console.log('get all Category types ', response);
      this.categoryTypes = response; 
    });
```

}

Comment: try to use `[ngValue]="elt.code"` instead of `value`

Comment: @PierreDuc thanks, this is not the ^problem i already used ngValue and it doesn't work

Comment: Check category.type value and its type

Comment: @KarthickSrinivasan thanks it is in the same type

Comment: @sk555 can you show mock objects of category and categoryTypes

Comment: @Asanka sure i edited the post

Comment: No i asked  in your code ->  elt of categoryTypes ,do the  elt has a property called type. Is elt and the category are same type (that means have same properties as code type?

Comment: @Asanka yes they have the same value for example categoty.type has "test" value and the same as elt.code

Comment: So @Anupam Singh answer should work?

Comment: @Asanka it doesn't really work for me, it is logic but it doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

In your **component** you should have something like :

```
 categoryTypes = [
    {value: 'val1', code: 'code1'},
    {value: 'val2', code: 'code2'}
    ];

 category: { type :string, } = { type: 'code1' }; // this would be selected val
```

Take a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbxkrh

Comment: thanks for this answer. I have it and the category.type contains a value

Comment: this doesn't really work for me, the same thing i did

Comment: the reason may be the categoryService, but not sure. can you generate stackblitz for your issue?

Comment: even the sevice i tried to mock the categoryTypes in typescript without invoking the service and it doesn't work. i will generate the stackblitz to see

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses object identity to select option that is why it is not preselected

> To customize the default option comparison algorithm, 
>   supports compareWith input. compareWith takes a function which has two
>   arguments: option1 and option2. If compareWith is given, Angular
>   selects option by the return value of the function.

**component.html**

```
   <select class="form-control col-sm-8" id="type" [compareWith]="compareFn" 
       [(ngModel)]="category.type" 
       name="type">
              <option *ngFor="let elt of categoryTypes" [ngValue]="elt">
                {{elt.value}}
              </option>
        </select>
```

**component.ts**

```
 compareFn(option1,option2): boolean {
        return option1.type=option2.type;
    }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iwjghz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Ref:https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

Comment: is there any difference in angular's versioon using that ? I am working on angular 5 CLI 1.5.2

Comment: It doesn't work for me i upgraded to angular 6 and it doesn't work

Comment: are you getting any error or share your object structure

Comment: the is no error even the structure i changed to the one u setted in stackblitz example and it doesn't work

Comment: can you share that stackblitz example?